# SharePoint 2013 - editable region on elements

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Is there anyway I can create an editable region on an element? for example, I have the following code in my .htm page layout....

```
<div id="content-left" class="participate"></div>
```

and I would like to have the flexibility to edit this element's attributes from the browser while editing a page,  so that I have something like..

```
<div id="content-left" class="<?sharepoint rich text field to edit?>"></div>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Web Part with editable properties and whatever the user set on the text property, you can use it as class on your div in Web Part..

I don't think its possible without a Web Part, either a Content Editor Web Part having this HTML, so your user can directly change the class or something configurable like a custom web part